# Does AWS Amplify Datastore (GraphQL API) use HTTPS for Queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I was wondering if the CRUD queries are encrypted in transit. I have a flutter app that uses AWS as backend and the data sent from client server needs to be encrypted in transit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it uses TLS encryption and you can read more about that here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/encryption-in-transit.html

Comment: but this is for amplify hosting, or? Isn't that a different service? Or does amplify datastore rely on it for transfer of data? THANK YOU!